# How do I access type use annotations in kotlin through reflection?

Tags: java, kotlin, reflection, types, annotations

A [library](https://github.com/FabLabsMC/fiber) I'm using utilises type use annotations to add constraints to variables. For example, if you wanted a configurable opacity (in percent, represented by a `float`), you'd annotate the `float` type:

```java
public @Setting.Constrain.Range(min = 0, max = 1, step = 0.1) float opacity = 1f;
```

I could not get the same library to work on identical kotlin code.

To simplify the question, let's declare the annotation and usage ourselves:

```java
@Target(ElementType.TYPE_USE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface JavaAnnot { }
```

```java
public class TestJava {

    @JavaAnnot int a = 5;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(TestJava.class.getDeclaredFields()[0].getAnnotatedType().isAnnotationPresent(JavaAnnot.class));
    }

}
```

Running `TestJava#main` yields `true`, indicating that the `JavaAnnot` annotation is present on the type.

If we introduce a new kotlin class `TestKotlin` with a similar `a` field and annotated type:

```kotlin
class TestKotlin {

    val a: @JavaAnnot Int = 5

}
```

The previous check, now on the `TestKotlin` class:

```
TestKotlin.class.getDeclaredField("a").getAnnotatedType().isAnnotationPresent(JavaAnnot.class)
```

yields **`false`**, indicating that the `JavaAnnot` annotation is NOT present on the `Int` type of `a`, even though we clearly did annotate it.

I've tried:

- Annotating `a` with `@JvmField`. This did not change the behaviour.
- Declaring an identical annotation in kotlin:

```kotlin
@Target(AnnotationTarget.TYPE)
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
annotation class KotlinAnnot
```

```kotlin
val a: @KotlinAnnot Int = 5
```

Did not fix the problem.

- Inspecting other metadata accessible through reflection: I did not find anything useful.

Is this a kotlin bug? Do type use annotations not exist in kotlin, or is the syntax different? What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Annotations of AnnotatedType of Kotlin fields are stored with Kotlin Metadata annotation and can be accessed only by Kotlin Reflection.

Update:

Since Kotlin 1.4.0, the compiler writes type annotations as it is expected.

Comment: Do you have a source for this? In the example you can clearly see I am accessing the type use annotation through reflection, but only successfully on the Java class.

Comment: @086, the annotation is not actually added to the type of field, it is stored in Kotlin Metadata, so it can be accessed only with Kotlin reflection.